# FCM Push Notification showing without onMessage

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send the push notification using Firebase in web `</>`. It display the push notification and it is working fine. However when I try to access the `console.log(payload)` in the function

```
messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
    console.log(payload);
    const noteTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const noteOptions = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
        icon: payload.notification.icon,
    };
    new Notification(noteTitle, noteOptions);
});
```

there is no output in the console, `onMessage` is not called, However the push notification is successfull

My question is from where do the message is sent to push notification?
I need to show the notification in the top navigation bar.How do I append notification to the navigation bar?

Comment: It is not working now. Push Notification is not sent.It was working just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the first table in the documentation on [receiving messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive), you'll see that notification messages are automatically displayed by the SDK when your page is not active. So in this situation notifications will be displayed, even when you don't write an `onMessage` handler.

This mimics the behavior of notifications on mobile platforms, where the OS displays these messages when the app is not active.

If you don't want messages to be displayed by the SDK/OS, you can send a `data` message - which is always delivered to your `onMessage` and never displayed automatically.

Comment: How to send data message

Comment: Any message with a `data` child without a `notification` part is a data message, so: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Comment: can I sent two message one with notification and one without notification